# Users with little reputation supplying poor answers

Tags: support, new-users, answers, spamming

Maybe it's just me, but over the last few days, I've been noticing a *lot* of users with anywhere from 1-10 reputation answering questions with **terrible** answers. Some of them almost seem like a poorly written bot that just rips key words from the post and then attempts to string together an answer. Has anyone noticed this influx of weird/poor answers? Is this something new or something that I've just been picking up on more? I suddenly understand why many posts are protected against users with no rep from answering.

Comment: It's pretty much all one person.

Comment: It's all due to our resident troll. He has some kind of mental condition so that he usually writes gibberish. He is on long term suspension, but keeps creating temporary new accounts to break in and tweak the noses of the mods, sometimes even saying deliberately inflammatory stuff to the mods.